# Make jQuery re-run if statement on windows resize.

Tags: jquery, browser, resize

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var widwith = $(window).width();
    if(widwith < 1150) {
        $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(){
            $('.sub-menu').toggleClass('sub-display');
        });
    }else if(widwith > 1150) {
        $('.menu-item-has-children').hover(function(){
            $('.sub-menu').toggleClass('sub-display');
        });
    }
});
```

it detects the window width, and depending on the width makes a sub menu apear on either click (on mobile) or hover on desktop. The issue I am having is if you resize the window I need ot re-run the if statement in case is crosses over the threshold of 1150px wide... but I have no idea how I would do this? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
        resize();
    });
    resize();
});

function resize()
{
  var widwith = jQuery(window).width();
    if(widwith < 1150) {
        jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(){
            jQuery('.sub-menu').toggleClass('sub-display');
        });
    }else if(widwith > 1150) {
        jQuery'.menu-item-has-children').hover(function(){
            jQuery('.sub-menu').toggleClass('sub-display');
        });
    }
}
```

Just add a window resize handler.

Comment: would I put this inside the $(document).ready or does that become unnecessary?

Comment: you ca define it inside in order to make sure the dom is ready when you hook it up

Comment: nope... not working... it stops the rest of the code from working... i'm using the jQuery(document).ready(function($){}); syntax because im working with wordpress... would that make a difference?

Comment: Keep in mind that it will fire whenever your browser is resized.

Comment: Updated to use jQuery instead

Comment: ok... so now it seems to be working after the page re-sizes... and it does execute the correct code... but it no longer works on page load... the page must be re sized for it to run... ? do I need to duplicate the code outside the resize function but in the .ready?

Comment: Just move it out to a function that you call outside the handler as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery's [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) method

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   // put yout code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  First you need to pull the core resize event logic into a separate function so you can re-use:

```
function resize() {
    var widwith = $(window).width();
    if(widwith < 1150) {
         $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(){
              $('.sub-menu').toggleClass('sub-display');
         });
    }else if(widwith > 1150) {
         $('.menu-item-has-children').hover(function(){
              $('.sub-menu').toggleClass('sub-display');
          });
    }
}
```

Which will make your document on ready listener look like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    resize();
});
```

Then add an event listener for the resize event:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
     resize();
});
```

That should do it.

Comment: not working.... would is have some thing to do with the jQuery(document).ready(function($){}); syntax I'm using due to wordpress?

Comment: Yes, change the $ to jQuery for the ready and resize handlers